# The usage of "side"

Tags: science, scientific-language, tech-writing

I am currently working on scientific writing in English. I am trying to describe a plane with an elliptical hole, and this hole has two cracks. The cracks are collinear, positioned on the left and right sides. Can I express it as: 'Infinite plate containing an elliptical hole with cracks **on both sides**,' or 'Two cracks emanating from the elliptical hole in an infinite plate'?

Which expression is more accurate? Is the use of articles inappropriate?
[image]

Comment: "with two cracks on opposite sides" might be better here. Although there are more precise alternatives, e.g. "centered on the positive and negative x-axis".

Comment: Which articles are you concerned about? Do you want to add or remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two cracks; they radiate out from the elliptical hole as projections along both sides of the major axis.